# SQL Server : dynamic pivot over many columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, pivot

I have a table that looks like this:

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (
 fldID bigint
,fldYear bigint
,fldMonth bigint
,fldMonthName nvarchar(350)
,fldPayrollId bigint
,fldFullName nvarchar(350)
,fldDailyWage float
,fldMonthlyWage  float
,fldkarkardDay  float
,fldPriceMaskan  float
,fldPriceChild float
,fldPriceFood  float
,fldAllAdditions  float
,fldPriceTax  float
,fldPriceSanavat  float
,fldPriceEzafeKari  float
,fldPriceEidiPadash  float
,fldEmployeeShare  float
,fldEmployerShare  float
,fldUnemploymentShare  float
,fldSumEmployer  float);
```

like so

```
insert @Temp(fldID, fldYear, fldMonth, fldMonthName, fldPayrollId, fldFullName, fldDailyWage, fldMonthlyWage , fldkarkardDay , fldPriceMaskan , fldPriceChild, fldPriceFood , fldAllAdditions , fldPriceTax , 
fldPriceSanavat, fldPriceEzafeKari , fldPriceEidiPadash , fldEmployeeShare , fldEmployerShare , fldUnemploymentShare , fldSumEmployer  )
values(1, 1400, 2, N'February', 212, N'500000', N'6500', N'29', N'52000', N'98750', N'1900000', N'900000', N'30000', N'900000', N'60000', N'650000', N'0', N'0', N'1900000', N'256000', N'256000'),(2, 1399, 3, N'March'   , 214, N'5200000', N'0', N'30', N'65900', N'6520', N'1900000', N'1000', N'98500', N'1900000', N'1900000', N'1900000', N'0', N'1900000', N'0', N'256000', N'0'),(3, 1400, 4, N'April'   , 216, N'62200000', N'35600', N'30', N'87900', N'65000', N'0', N'6520', N'1900000', N'1900000', N'0', N'1900000', N'1900000', N'1900000', N'1900000', N'256000', N'25600'),(4, 1399, 5, N'May'       , 218, N'522000', N'85000', N'2800', N'65400', N'52200', N'0', N'14780', N'1900000', N'1900000', N'0', N'1900000', N'0', N'1900000', N'1900000', N'256000', N'0')
```

I'm trying the pivot it as follows:

[image]

My code is as follows but the pivot command cannot identify the code and the correct output

```
SELECT 
     N'parameter' parameter
    ,p.fldMonthName 
    ,p.fldCols
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        N'[fldDailyWage],[fldMonthlyWage],[fldkarkardDay],[fldPriceMaskan],[fldPriceChild],[fldPriceFood],[fldAllAdditions],[fldPriceTax]' fldCols
        ,* 
    FROM @Temp where fldYear = 1399
) x
PIVOT  
(
    count(fldID)
    FOR fldMonthName IN (fldCols)
) p
```

Comment: That is an unpivot, not a pivot.

Comment: Side note, storing monetary values in a `float` is a *terrible* idea. Use a Base 10 numerical data type. Unless it's intentional that you want someone who paid `200.20` in tax has their tax value stored as `200.1999969482421875` (which'll cause all sorts of rounding errors down the line)

Comment: It's an UNPIVOT followed by a PIVOT of the month.  Do you really have to do this in TSQL?  Pivoting and unpivoting for display is better done in the front-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use unpivot with grouping by column parameter as follows:

```
Select u.parameter, Sum(Case When fldMonth=2 Then u.value End) As 'February',
                    Sum(Case When fldMonth=5 Then u.value End) As 'May'
From
(
select fldMonth, [fldDailyWage],[fldMonthlyWage],[fldkarkardDay],[fldPriceMaskan],[fldPriceChild],[fldPriceFood],[fldAllAdditions],[fldPriceTax]
from @Temp) t
unpivot
( 
  value
  for parameter in ([fldDailyWage],[fldMonthlyWage],[fldkarkardDay],[fldPriceMaskan],[fldPriceChild],[fldPriceFood],[fldAllAdditions],[fldPriceTax])
) u
Group by u.parameter
```